# How to graph functions with removable discontinuity using some software?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I find it difficult to graph a function with a removable discontinuity accurately using WolframAlpha or TI Calculators. Virtually all software that I am aware of would graph the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{x}$ as a continuous function. Even using TikZ package with latex, I do not know how the system will take care of the removable discontinuity automatically (though this part of the question should be asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Plot a bunch of points and draw curves between them. https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph